# Writing into a file in a specific line without any data format

Tags: java

What i am trying to do is when a user wants to edit his profile and then press on save changes i want to get the text from all the JTextFields and write into a the file at that specific line. However after 3 days of trying no luck. I have looked over all the posts here about reading and writing into files but without any luck ok all the methods are below and i will explain them

```
public void save() throws IOException{
    String changes = name.getText() + "" + dob.getText() + "" 
            + "" + address.getText() + "" + town.getText() 
            + "" + number.getText();
    String whichLine = this.staff_no.getText();
    this.name.setEditable(false);
    this.dob.setEditable(false);
    this.address.setEditable(false);
    this.town.setEditable(false);
    this.number.setEditable(false);
    users.saveChanges(changes,whichLine);
}
```

here i am create a String with all the text from the JTextFields setting them back to false and calling the saveChanges method(the one that is suppose to "replace" this new String)

```
public int getIndex(String staffno){
    for(User user : allUsers){
        if(user.getStaff_No().contains(staffno)){
            this.index = allUsers.indexOf(staffno);
            break;
        }
    }
    return this.index;
}

public void saveChanges(String changes, String whichLine) throws IOException{
    try {
        int count = 0;
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("records.txt", true);
        bw = new BufferedWriter(writer);
        while(scan.hasNext()){
            count++;
            if(count == getIndex(whichLine)){
                bw.write(changes);
                bw.newLine();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        if(bw != null){
            bw.close();
            reader.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Now here i am getting the Staffno of the user and running it through my ArrayLists of users to find its index lets say its 0. and then i am looping through the scanner i previously opened and trying to find which line to i can overwrite that line. However i run into Exception errors such as Stream closed or NoSuchAnElementException or no error at all but doesnt write my line or saves it.

Here is the method where i open the file

```
public void open(){
    try {
        URL path = Users.class.getResource("records.txt");
        File f = new File(path.getFile());
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
        scan = new Scanner(reader);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }
}
```

Reason i dont close the scanner is because i will keep using it for other stuff

I realise this is a specific scenarion and not a simple read/write scenario so any help is MUCH appreciated.

Comment: You cannot write to the middle of a file (well, you can, but it's rather tricky). You have to rewrite the whole file, changing the line you want.

Comment: Well what i am trying to do is as i read through the file if i find the line i want i overwrite it...if it is that difficult i am open to suggestions:)

Comment: Have you thought of using a database instead of a txt file?

Comment: we are not allowed to use database...only txt files to mimic the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do - overwriting data in the middle of a file - can only be done if you're writing the exact same number of bytes as you're replacing. That is, you can't overwrite a line in a file with a different line unless they're exactly the same number of bytes (not necessarily the same number of characters depending on the character coding).

You're also keeping a scanner open for a file that you're actively writing to which is just asking for buffering-related issues.

The absolutely easiest way of solving your issue would be to do what coolguy suggests and read all lines into memory, replace or add lines as you see fit and then write it all back.

However, if you can't or don't want to cache the whole file in memory you can read the file line for line and then write them back - after you've changed the relevant lines - to a different file, finishing off by replacing the old file with the new file.

```
public static void writeChanges(String changes, int whichLine) throws IOException {
    // The files we're working with
    final File database = new File("database.txt");
    final File newDatabase = new File("database.new.txt");
    try(BufferedReader reader = new Bufferedreader(
            new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(database)));
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(newDatabase)) {
        int line = 0;
        String line;
        // Keep reading lines from the source file until we've read them all
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if(line == whichLine) {
                // Write the modified line
                writer.println(changes);
            } else {
                // Write the original line
                writer.println(line);
            }
            line++;
        }
    }
    // Replace the old database with the new
    Files.move(newDatabase.toPath(), database.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
```

Comment: quick question on your example...say i implement this correctly and it works...my txt file will be renamed to database.new.txt? Reason i am asking is because a user may modify the files as many times he/she wants not just once. Thanks in advance

Comment: We're reading `database.txt` and writing the changes to `database.new.txt`, the we're replacing `database.txt` with `database.new.txt` so that `database.txt` is again the current database. Incidentally, this forces you to close and recreate your scanner since it now points to the wrong file.

Comment: i added in my code where it should be scan.close.....i cant close it in that method because i use it in another method to pass values to the User attributes

Comment: Why mix the NIO api and the `File` API - it's pretty horrible? Just use [`Files.lines`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-) and the `Stream` API to do this in a couple of lines...

Comment: Because `File.renameTo` doesn't throw any exceptions. Feel free to write your own answer using streams. I'm keeping this though since I'm more familiar with the "old" IO classes and `Files.move` is superior to `File.renameTo`

Answer (score 0):

If your file is not large you can do the following:

```
// File file = ...
// int yourLineNumber = ...
List<String> lines = FileUtils.readLines(new FileReader(file));
lines.add(yourLineNumber, "Line to add");
FileUtils.writeLines(file, lines);
```

I use [commons-io](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io) library in this code.

Comment: Why recommend the commons IO library when this functionality is readily available [in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html)? Furthermore the commons IO library uses the ancient and rather rubbish `File` API rather than the `Path` API. I really wish people would stop spreading these terrible examples from 2010 around the internet...

Comment: @BoristheSpider you can say the same about almost any library. Besides I don't think you should care about what API `commons-io` uses. It could've use `Path` with the same result. P.S. I don't say you should use `File` in your new code.

Comment: No. There is no reason to include a library whose last update was in 2012 into new code, when the code the library creates is more verbose and lest robust than the utilities provided by the JDK. This example is as unhelpful as the people who post examples of Java collections from Java 1.4, before generics had been added to the JDK.

Comment: You are welcome to post an answer using `Path` API, I'd be happy to compare it :) But I'm sure you can't achieve it with less code. But maybe it can be a better solution if you don't need any other functionality of `commons-io`.